# How to read variables from CSV in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am having a CSV file with few values.
I want to read that values into variables in terraform.

I have used giving locals with file path . But it shows path not found. How can I read variables from CSV in terraform.

I am having my git structure like below.
[image]

where Key_vault folder is having my terraform codes.And adf_confg is having my csv file.

my main.tf is like this.
[image]

I am getting error: Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at ./adf_config/datasets.csv; this function works only with files that
│ are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in this
│ configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource

Comment: What is your actual TF code and precisely the error that you get?

Comment: The error is clear: "no file exists at ./adf_config/datasets.csv"

Answer (score 2):

If your Terraform module is in the `Key_Vault` directory and your CSV file is in `adf_config` then the path from the Terraform module to the CSV file must start with `../` to traverse to the parent directory.

I would also typically suggest using `path.module` to be explicit that we're writing a path relative to the current module, although when your module is the root module it doesn't really make any difference because `path.module` will always be `.` (the current directory) in that case. Using `path.module` can help with refactoring this configuration into a child module later though, since it will already be clear what this path is relative to.

```
locals {
  datasets = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/../adf_config/datasets.csv"))
}
```